# scp from remote server to ec2-instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, scp, remote-desktop, connection-timeout

I want to copy a folder from remote ubuntu to ec2-instance tried the below at remote ubuntu machine

```
scp -i </path/of/ec2_pemkey> -r <folder that I wanna copy> user@<ip of ec2>:/path/where/I wanna/copy
```

I copied my pem to remote and changed permissions chmod 400

error: connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

I missed adding ip address of my remote ubuntu machine to security groups of my ec2 instance. Once done, I was able to scp from remote ubuntu to ec2 instance.

Make sure security group type is SSH which enables port 22

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain your Answer a little more clearly? What do you mean by "adding ip of my remote to ec2"? Please help future readers learn how to avoid a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Connection Time out means that your local can't be able to reach the remote.
to debug :

- Check if your remote machine authorize traffic from port 22 ( Security Group)
- Check if You have the good public IP of your machine

If its was an error with your pem key or user (ubuntu) you will receive an access denied error.

From you comment, that means its was the IP of the machine missing or not good.